# How to reset OpenCart 2+ administrative password?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

Apparently the new (v2) OpenCart's password encryption scheme is not a simple md5 hash. I attempted to search the net for a way to reset the admin password after I changed hosts for my OpenCart installtion but could not find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a new user. Copy that user's password over to your admin account.

Comment: @ceejayoz You'd also need to copy the salt value across

Comment: @JayGilford Hopefully they're using the industry standard bcrypt, in which case the salt is part of the hash.

Comment: If only that were true @ceejayoz - https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/user.php#L38

Comment: @JayGilford Ewwwwww. /me shudders

Comment: @Slavic I have updated one more alternative answer to this post i.e, simply navigating via website to generate passwords specifically to OpenCart 2.x

Answer (score 15):

If you just need to regain access, and change your password then you can do so pretty easily. Open `system/library/user.php` (`system/library/cart/user.php` in later versions) and find the line beginning

```
$user_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE username =
```

Before the `WHERE` put a `#` changing it to

```
$user_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user #WHERE username =
```

and save. This allows you to log in using the first account (usually the default admin account) without any user and password. As soon as you do, reverse this and save again. You'll still be logged in and can edit the user data editing the password as you wish

Comment: This saved me hours... BUT in the version of the file i had the line you have highlighted to search for appears twice, which caused some confusion.

Answer (score 4):

### RESET OPENCART ADMIN PASSWORD BY EDITING MySQL DATABASE Via `phpMyAdmin` or `MySQL` command prompt

The only way to reset the administrative `password` is modifying the password column in `oc_user` via `phpMyAdmin`, something like hunting the silk road or either by changing the `password` column via `MySQL` command prompt. You cannot generate new Salt & Hashing with `MySQL` command prompt as explained at the end. Follow these below steps:

Navigate to  `oc_user` table and look for columns with name password & salt 
and change the values for the desired `user_id`

**password: d1c194daffb03fc2653027c87f76a12a4eaeac5f**

**salt: x3x6r693j**

This combination of string or hash changes/alters the administrative password to “*`password`*” (without the quotes) for the *desired user*. This method might create a minor security risk as the salt will be a publicly known data, which is published here.

Click “Go”. It will change your password to password. Now, log into the OpenCart Admin (www.yourwebsitename.com/admin) Dashboard with your existing username and the new password.

**Username: < Existing Username >**

**Password: password**

By knowing your **user_id**, all the above steps are done from one command:

```
update `oc_user` set `password` = sha1( concat(`salt`, sha1( concat(`salt`, sha1('password'))))) where user_id = 1
```

**Explaination:**

The password was encrypted with the randomised salt

```
sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))
```

The above method is used to encrypt the password from the file **admin/model/user/user.php**

```
SELECT SHA1( CONCAT( salt, SHA1( CONCAT( salt, SHA1(  'password' ) ) ) ) ) 
FROM oc_user
WHERE user_id =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**Results:**
d1c194daffb03fc2653027c87f76a12a4eaeac5f

For **Salt:**

```
$salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)
```

`uniqid()`,  `password_hash` and `password_verify` are purely PHP functions. They have nothing to do with MySQL

password_hash does not use the MD5 algorithm for hashing you password. md5 and password_hash() produce two different lengths

---

Navigate to [Tool: OpenCart 2.0+ User Password Reset Generator](http://www.speckygeek.com/tools/opencart2-password-generator/)
you can specify your New Password and Salt

Comment: works for me, good point when you have access to DB


my OpenCart Version 3.0.3.1

Answer (score 3):

For login **admin** password **0ZReKeFZM75Y** set in `database > oc_user`

password **0c7a864c5a737f08f001f3123849ba5e03af3d06**

and salt **HYSQS59P9**

to admin user row.

Comment: Choose this if you want something fast and easy, just don't forget to change the password back after you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Password is stored by OpenCart (from `admin/model/user/user.php`) as

```
sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($data['password'])))
```

Assuming you have DB access you can retrieve the salt as

```
SELECT salt FROM your_db.oc_user WHERE username='your_username';
```

Then generate the new hash, e.g. in bash ($SALT being the result of the previous command) :

```
echo -n $SALT$(echo -n $SALT$(echo -n "newpassword" | sha1sum|cut -d' ' -f1 )|sha1sum|cut -d' ' -f1)|sha1sum
```

Finally, update the DB with this new hash :

```
UPDATAE your_db.oc_user SET password='newhash' WHERE username='your_username';
```

Then log in with the new password.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new password using the script below:

```
<?php    
  $salt = 'pMiPpQ7N4';   //salt, update user.salt with this
  $password = 'test123'; //actual password

  //update user.password with this
  echo sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password))); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the php files, open file system/library/cart/user.php in a text editor and change line 40, the 1st line of method login(), from:

```
$user_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE username = '" . $this->db->escape($username) . "' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) OR password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') AND status = '1'");
```

to:

```
$user_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE username = '" . $this->db->escape($username) . "' AND status = '1'");
```

This removes the password check,so you will always be logged in regardless the password you entered. **After you are logged in, immediately change this line back** as it will allow anybody to login under any user account, then change your password under "Users - Users - Edit".